# How can I start MainActivity(That its app compeltely killed) from the runnning service again when new data recieving from server(as an event)?

Tags: android, service, server

This is the scenario...

```
App is opened
User clicks on a button that starts a service.
(Service always is run in background and check recieving new data from server)
User presses home key and then long presses home key and clears application from task list completely.
Service continues to run, although app has closed.
```

I can determine whether that app has been killed or not by reading this link:
[How to determine app is running from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858526/how-to-determine-app-is-running-from-service)
How can I start MainActivity(That its app compeltely killed) from the runnning service again when new data recieving from server(as an event) ?

Comment: As a user I would not like when the app pops up a UI unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast an action and use a `BroadCastReceiver` to receive it and start the `MainActivity` from `onReceive` method of the `BroadCastReceiver`:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, ...)
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

or from a service use:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: But I do not use from broadcast. I use from service only. Must be use from broadcast ?

Comment: @setareab not necessarily, you can simple call startActivity(intent) within your service, but it is better to setup broadcast receiver. remember to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK since you are starting the activity from a service

Comment: But I have not  Context when MainActivity killed.

Comment: @setareab for the serivce you don't need context, just use startActivity

Comment: But this line has error in my service :Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.class,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: @setareab that was pseudo-code like, the correct way is mentioned in my edited post

Comment: Can you edit this for using from service instead of broadcast?

Comment: @setareab sure just use startActivity instead of context.startActivity

Comment: But this line has error in my service :Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.class,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: i use this:if(!isAppRunning())
        {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class); 
        
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(intent);
        }   But Can not start MainActivity When i exit from app. What is problem?